# how to center barcode image in the table?

Tags: html, css, xml, frontend, odoo

i'am trying to desgine barcode label in odoo it printed well if it short barcode otherwise the barcode go over the table border and i can't read it with reader also sometimes it print in 2 label if the the name is in first cell is long 
so i need to set fixed size for the table 
here is 2 screenshots for the labels 
[image: damaged label]

[image: good label but barcode need to be in center]

here is the code

```
 <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding:0;" align="center">
                    <table class="table table-bordered mb-0" width="50mm" style="padding:0"  >
                      <tr  style="font-size: 50%;;padding:0" align="center" valign="center">
 <td style="font-size: 110%;;padding:0">
                            <strong t-field="product.name"/>
</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="margin:0 auto;padding:0 auto;" align="center">
                        <td style="padding:1" align="center" colspan = "2">
                            <img t-if="product.barcode" t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' % ('Code128', product.barcode,600 ,150)" style="width:120%;height:30%;margin:0 auto;padding:0 auto;"/>
                            <br style="text-align: center;padding:1;">     
                                <span  style="font-size: 6px;text-align: center;" t-field="product.barcode"/>
                            </br>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="text-align: center;">
                        <td style="font-size: 50%;padding:0">www.autopartsegypt.com</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
             </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a working demo please, and also why are you using `width:120%` on `img` it must be `100%`

Comment: Can you increase table td width

Comment: @Awais if it 100% the reader can't read the barcode

Comment: @MohamedFouad but its against rules, width `100%` means its parent width what ever its mention there, there must be some `div` which have `margin` or static `width` which cause this issue, but without complete working code we just give you hints :(

Comment: @Awais this the whole code if width be 100% it be in center but i can't read it by reader

Comment: @MohamedFouad Then you need to wrap `image` inside some `div` and adjust it with using `overflow:hidden` as i can see there is some extra white space in your bar-code image

Comment: @Awais can you help me how to but it in dev i'am new to this field

Comment: @MohamedFouad I will, but the code you provided is not enough to make any output, just create a simple table add the static data which you show us in image and add your bar-code image url correctly so that we can see bar-code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207640/discussion-between-mohamed-fouad-and-awais).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `margin-right:1%;` on the img or table tag and increase the percentage as required.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this snippet , i use `object fit` with `width` , Do let me know if
>   that prints well, you can set its `width` to `100%` or in `px` what
>   ever you want

```css
img{
max-width: 100%;
}
.img-wrap img{
width: 200px;
object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered mb-0" style="text-align: center;" >
<tr >
<td >
<strong t-field="product.name">product.name</strong>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="margin:0 auto;padding:0 auto;" align="center">
<td style="padding:1" align="center" colspan = "2"><div class="img-wrap">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqCU0.gif" style=""/></div>
<br style="text-align: center;padding:1;">
<span style="" t-field="product.barcode">product.barcode</span>

</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center;">
<td style="">www.autopartsegypt.com</td>
</tr>
</table>
```